# Azure DevOps release with multiple artifacts coming from the same branch

Tags: azure-devops

We have two build pipelines building from two different paths in the same repository.

**BuildPipelineA** builds **/PathA** from **AppRepo** and publishes the artifact **ArtifactA**

**BuildPipelineB** builds **/PathB** from **AppRepo** and publishes the artifact **ArtifactB**

We then have a release pipeline that uses both these artifacts to deploy the application to some WebApps.

As a branching strategy we're using a custom Gitflow Workflow. The only difference is that we have two development teams, each with their own integration branch. So basically instead of having the classic `develop` branch, we've got `develop`, `develop-teamAlpha` and `develop-teamBeta`. The triggers are set to all three branches, in addition to `master`, `release/` and `hotfix/`, so that's a total of six branches that are being targeted.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a CI/CD process in place that will always take artifacts from the matching(same) branch for the automatically triggered release creation.

For example, given a previous `master`**ArtifactB** exists:

- A developer commits changes on `master` for some files in **/PathA**
- **BuildPipelineA** triggers and builds **ArtifactA** from `master`
- The **ReleasePipeline** should now create a new release using `master`**ArtifactA** and `master`**ArtifactB**

I want the same thing to happen even if the triggering artifact comes from a different branch:

- A developer commits changes on `develop` for some files in **/PathB**
- **BuildPipelineB** triggers and builds **ArtifactB** from `develop`
- The **ReleasePipeline** should now create a new release using `develop`**ArtifactB** and (existing)`develop`**ArtifactA**

---

***Try 1:***
So the first thing I've tried was to use $(Release.Artifacts.ArtifactA.SourceBranch) as a source branch for **ArtifactB**:

[image: Release.Artifacts.webapp.SourceBranch example]

This doesn't work because this variable depends on the release to already have its artifacts selected.

***Try 2:*** My second attempt was to create a new pipeline that would combine the two artifacts, while making sure they are the latest from a specific, matching branch.

This build would be triggered by the completion of any of **BuildPipelineA** or **BuildPipelineB**. I used some API calls to get the source branch of the triggering build, and I used this to download **ArtifactA** and **ArtifactB** from the matching branch, and then publish the new, combined, **ArtifactC**.

Since the source repository for this "combining pipeline" is irrelevant, I chose to use a second repository where I stored my scripts that I used for the API calls.

Now by doing this, I have no control over the branch used to create a new release from the **ArtifactC**(combined artifact), because the sources for this artifact are always coming from the second repository's `master` branch. This also makes me lose all traceability offered by Azure DevOps. The following example might make things clearer:

[image: ArtifactC]

In addition, it won't integrate at all with the artifact filtering setup that we use for each different environment.

---

I'm very open to any suggestions.

Comment: looking for similar answers for a long time... btw, have you tried to build ArtifactC from the same repo?

Comment: I also need a solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple release pipeline, one for each environnement, with the same tasks and stages but different branch selections and deploy filters (prod release pipeline with prods branchs). But it's not easy to maintain after.

I'ved also tried to use $(Build.SourceBranchName) as source branch with no luck
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBHye.png)

Even with a custom variable, pre setuped.
[capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuMfn.png)